# Leaflet: Resize markers in layer when zoom in

Tags: leaflet, zoom

May I ask how to resize markers in layer when zoom in?

```
var map = L.map('map', {
     center: [23.364739, 115.187951],
     zoom: 11,
     minZoom: 11, 
     maxZoom: 18,
});

var ar_icon = L.Icon.extend({
});

var ar_icon_1 = new ar_icon({iconUrl: '../_image/arrows/line_ar_0.png',     iconSize: [11, 11]});
var ar_icon_2 = new ar_icon({iconUrl: '../_image/arrows/line_ar_1.png',     iconSize: [22, 22]});

var all_testptLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("../data/test_geojson.php", {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {.
        if (feature.properties.num < 0.5)
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: ar_icon_1});
        else if (feature.properties.num < 1.0)
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: ar_icon_2});
    }
}

all_testptLayer.addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function() {
   var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
   if (currentZoom>12) {
   // what should I do here to access all markers in the all_testptLayer and change the size of all markers to double in size?
   }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have all your markers inside a `L.GeoJSON`, which is a subclass of `L.LayerGroup`, so you can use the `eachLayer` method, like...

```
all_testptLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    // Do something with each marker inside all_testptLayer
});
```

You will have to combine this with the `setIcon` method of `L.Marker`, and the fact that layers created from a GeoJSON factory have a reference to the GeoJSON data inside their `feature` property, so something like:

```
var ar_icon_1 = ...;
var ar_icon_2 = ...;
var ar_icon_1_double_size = ...;
var ar_icon_2_double_size = ...;


map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoom > 12) {
        all_testptLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            if (layer.feature.properties.num < 0.5)
                return layer.setIcon(ar_icon_1);
            else if (feature.properties.num < 1.0)
                return layer.setIcon(ar_icon_2);
        });
    } else {
        all_testptLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            if (layer.feature.properties.num < 0.5)
                return layer.setIcon(ar_icon_1_double_size);
            else if (feature.properties.num < 1.0)
                return layer.setIcon(ar_icon_2_double_size);
        });
    }
});
```

Further optimizations are possible. The most obvious one is to tore the state of the icon size, in order to *not* change the icons at each zoom level change (that code will change the icons on every zoom change, most probably to the *same* icons, wasting CPU time and needless DOM changes).

Comment: Just would like to ask one more question:
How to do if I want to change the icon to a circle marker when zoom in?
E.g.,  
`var activeMarkerOptions = {
 radius: 10,
 fillColor: "#afff00",
 color: "#000",
 weight: 1,
 opacity: 1,
 fillOpacity: 0.9
};

if (layer.feature.properties.num < 0.5)
      return layer.setIcon(L.circleMarker([How to specify lat long here], activeMarkerOptions));`

Comment: It seems L.circleMarker is a vector layer.... Maybe the only way I could do this is to create a icon with a circle png file using iconUrl option....

Answer (score 6):

Use **setIcon()** to change the markers icon in a layer:

```
var layer = '';//define the layer that contains the markers
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

    //Update X and Y based on zoom level
    var x= 50; //Update x 
    var y= 50; //Update Y         
    var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            iconSize:     [x, y] // Change icon size according to zoom level
        }
    });
    layer.setIcon(LeafIcon);
});
```

**Reference:**
http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed I have read the suggestion answered by @juliabulia245 before but the suggestion seems applicable to L.CircleMarker only.

Comment: I have tried the following but doesn't work:
    `map.on('zoomend', function() {
        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
        if (currentZoom>12) {
             all_testptLayer.setStyle({iconSize: [200,200]});
        }
    });`

Comment: Aha, you need to use setIcon

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate more?
I tried
`all_testptLayer.setIcon({iconSize: [200,200]});`
but it returns `test.php:157 Uncaught TypeError: all_testptLayer.setIcon is not a function`

Comment: answer updated, check please

Comment: I also tried `all_testptLayer.setIcon(ar_icon_2);` to change all markers to ar_icon_2 when zoom but same error found in console

Comment: try latest script "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"

Comment: IvanSanchez mentioned an important point:
"You have all your markers inside a L.GeoJSON, which is a subclass of L.LayerGroup, so you can use the eachLayer method"
So I need to use the `eachLayer` method together with the `setIcon` method

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to define special class name while creating your markers and then on zoomend event to change the scale in CSS for defined class name

Comment: Nope, if you just scale you will change the icon size but coordinates are not correct.